# Writing to a memory location in assembly x86-64 AT&T

Tags: assembly, x86-64, att

I'm trying to move data from a memory location to another memory location and then print the result. But all I get is some garbage value and I can't figure out why.
The relevant code is below:

```
.bss 
code: .skip 1000000

.data 
smth: .asciz "somerandomtext"
format_str: .asciz "Contents of code:\n%s"

.text
main:
pushq %rbp
movq %rsp, %rbp

movq $smth , %rdi    # move address of smth in rdi
movq $code , %rax    # move address of code in rax
movq %rdi , (%rax)   # move contents of rdi to address stored in rax ??

movq $0 , %rax
movq $code , %rsi
movq $format_str , %rdi
call printf

movq %rbp, %rsp
popq %rbp
```

I know that my choice of registers is not ideal, I encountered this problem while working on something else.

Comment: `movq %rdi , (%rax)` is moving the address because you did `movq $smth, %rdi`. Use `movq smth, %rdi` without the `$` to load the first 8 bytes of your `smth`.

Comment: Thanks for replying. Suppose I want to move more than 8 bytes. Then I'd have to loop through smth? Isn't there a more direct way?

Comment: You can use `rep movsb` which is still a loop in disguise (and requires some setup).

Comment: Thank you very much! In the end I computed the length of the string and then used rep movsb to move that many bytes. Post that as an answer so I can accept it :)

Comment: @Razvycs self-answers on SO are welcome as long as they are detailed/explanatory enough, it's actually good exercise to try to write up good answer, although expect it to be a bit time consuming. Also in case you misunderstood something or you have still some bugs in code, you will often get further advice in comments...